# Realm database difficulties in IOS application

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently developing an application, and I am facing some problems I can not solve.

I currently have two views:

1. First view is a tableView representing my Realm objects.
2. Second view is for adding objects to my Realm database.

My problem is that, after adding a new object to my Realm database and immediately returning to the first view, sometimes the `tableView` does not recognize the newly added object but sometimes it does.

I hope this is information enough - ask me questions if needed.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setupDataForViewTable()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func setupDataForViewTable() {
    let realmm = try! Realm()
    let cryptocurrenciesFromDatabase = realmm.objects(crypto.self)
    for crypto in cryptocurrenciesFromDatabase{
        //For debugging
        if crypto.name.count <= 0{
            continue
        }
        let ROI = 0.0
        let change24h = 0.0
        let totalHolding = Double(crypto.buyingPrice) * Double(crypto.amount)
        cryptoCurrencies.append((name : crypto.name, amount : crypto.amount, ROI : ROI, change24h : change24h, total : totalHolding))
    }
}
```

Then there is the code from the second view, where i add stuff:

```
func updateCryptoInRealmDatabase(name : String, buyingPrice : Double, amount : Double){
    DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
        autoreleasepool {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let objectToUpdate = realm.objects(crypto.self).filter("name CONTAINS %@", name).first
            try! realm.write {
                objectToUpdate!.buyingPrice = (objectToUpdate!.buyingPrice + buyingPrice) / 2
                objectToUpdate!.amount += amount
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sadly, this is not enough information. Please edit your question to make it on-topic as explained in the help page: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: Do you update your datasource (the list of Realms object) and reload the tableView? You should do it after you create a new Realm item.

Comment: Do you have a `notificationToken` registered on your Results?

Comment: This i embarrassing. In my `updateCryptoInRealmDatabase()` i instantiate another realm instance. This was the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that tableView is updated when you navigate back to the first view. If that view is holding reference to Realm object and second view edited `List` in that object then it is enough to reload table. If you are holding reference to query of Realm objects then it will be refreshed automatically by Realm after commit update.

You can simply reload the view after it is shown again or register for [Realm notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) and update the view as the second view does changes to it.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If first view showing (same) Realm object  that second view is editing then data is already up to date. We will get fresh count of related objects here:

```
func titleTableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return realmObject.relatedObjects.count
}
```

Update: Fixed refresh need for Realm `Result` and added link to notifications in Realm documentation.

Comment: Actually it is not necessary to reload the query reference to upload the Table View. The Realm querys are always updated to match the latest results. I'd suggest as an answer to use a Notification. Actually there is some really valuable info on the [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) at the _Collection notifications_ section.

Comment: @Orlando Thanks for comment. I update my answer to mention that there is no need to update Result and notifications can be used to reload table.